# Design a database for user management system

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am designing a user management system.

The user can be a manager or a simple user. If the manager logs in he should be able to see all employees or users working under him.

Example:

```
M1 -> U1, U2, M11

and M11-> U3, U4, M12

and M12 -> U5, U6, U7
```

when M1 logs in he should see data of U1, U2, M11, U3, U4, M12, U5, U6, U7

and if M12 logs in then U5, U6, U7 only.

Comment: can you provide your Table Structure and data

Comment: So you are looking for a database design, i.e. you want to know what tables and columns to create best for this?

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly then below is a sample

```
DECLARE @tblEmployee AS TABLE ( EmployeeId INT IDENTITY(1,1),
                                    FName       VARCHAR(100),
                                    LName       VARCHAR(100),
                                    ManagerId   INT  NULL --  Reference of EmployeeId 
                                    )
```

You can achieve the task by above table structure and apply **CTE** Common table Expression for retrival.

The other way around Hierarchy Data type is https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/lesson-1-1-examining-the-current-structure-of-the-employee-table?view=sql-server-2017